# How to check if an element exists in a list in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is some code:

```
test_list = list(range(0, 100))
number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ")
if (guess in test_list): 
    print ("You have entered a number between 1 and 100")
```

Now if I run this, it doesn't work. Just doesn't work. It leaves me with this and nothing else:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is the correct way to check if an element exists in a list?

I had found this method on a website called 'GeeksForGeeks'

This code was written in the PyCharm IDE

Comment: `number = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100: "))`

Comment: ok will try : )

Comment: Works, thx for the help

Answer (score 3):

Change guess to number and convert input string to int

```
test_list = list(range(0, 100))
number = input("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ")
if int(number) in test_list: 
    print ("You have entered a number between 1 and 100")
```